# How to indent files in windows explorer to the left in right-to-left Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, right-to-left

I have a computer with Windows installed in a right-to-left language (such as Arabic or Hebrew). This means that the GUI is in Arabic\Hebrew and is Right-to-Left (yes, Start button is on the right and all...). In this installation Windows Explorer indents the files to the right side of the window.

Is there a way to configure Windows to indent the files to the left?
For Win XP? Vista? Win7?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I always wondered how this looks like and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I agree I'd like to see a screenshot.  Also, you still want right-to-left text order, though, right?  It seems like that would be awkward to read. (I know right-aligned English text hurts my eyes.)

Answer (score 0):

Your right-to-left Windows just does what it should do, but you want the opposite alignment (probably so it looks more like the view in a left-to-right system). I'd **look for a tool that could right-align the view on a left-to-right Windows.**

See if you can find tools to create Windows skins. If there are tools that can make my Windows look like a Mac, then I'd hope that these tools could also control the horizontal alignment of list views - which is exactly what you're looking for.

I have no experience in this area, but I would start googling for *Windows* and *skin* or *skinning* or *mod* or *modding*.